# Не работает ajax в теме вордпресс

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Пытаюсь настроить сайт на вордпресс с темой оформления vg-skybook. Все установилось нормально, все работает, НО когда добавляешь товар в корзину в консоли браузера появляется 500 ошибка. Товар в корзину добавляется, но модальное окно с товаром, которое берет данные по ajax не показывается. Также виджет корзины в правом верхнем углу не отображается - опять таки, не может получить по ajax данные https://prnt.sc/mkwdcz
Сначала грешил на хостинг - связывался с техподдержкой, но вроде не по ним.
Это глюк темы и с этим ничего не поделать?

Comment: Смотрите логи сервера, ошибка в серверной части, возможно не хватает какого расширения для php.

Comment: Вот логи хостинга, что-то все равно непонятно куда рыть дальше....82.209.214.34 - - [15/Feb/2019:16:14:19 +0300] "POST /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/1.0" 500 2342 "http://book-test.host1652635.hostland.pro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36" book-test.host1652635.hostland.pro

Comment: это access.log, нужны записи с error.log